# Is jQuery a client-side or a server-side JavaScript library?

Tags: jquery

Is jQuery a client-side or a server-side JavaScript library?

Comment: a very quick google or a browse through a couple of the many jquery questions on here would answer your question

Comment: I have trouble digesting the server-side Javascript library...

Comment: jQuery is the original framework to end all frameworks.  It's cross-universe compatible.  You should use it in everything, even in Perl

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Jquery is a client side library used for:

- **Traversing the DOM:** Selecting every other paragraph, or getting all the child elements inside a list, for example.
- **Manipulating the DOM:** Wrapping every link in a div tag, changing all tables to red.
- **Ajax:** Sending requests to the server and retrieving and displaying the response the server sends back, without refreshing the whole page.
- **Animation:** Fade in, Slide Up, grow, shrink, move, etc.
- **Browser normalization:** Make all browsers behave the same way with the same jquery code.

Answer (score 5):

jQuery is a client side framework that mostly caters toward DOM manipulation and abstracts many DOM methods so you can save lots of typing.

DOM:

```
var as = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
```

jQuery:

```
$('a')
```

It also solves a lot of browser discrepancies so you have more time for rapid development and not have to worry about low-level inconsistencies.

Answer (score 4):

jQuery is a client-side Javascript Framework which you can include in your HTML code using the `<script src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>` tag.

Comment: Is this answer really the "best" answer?  I'm not trying to get extra votes here, but this answer seems woefully incomplete.

Comment: The question was answered here, short and sweet like the question. It was your choice to go the extra mile. It is hardly a woefully incomplete answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's a JavaScript framework that abstracts many complex tasks into well tested methods that are wrapped in the jQuery function.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is client side

Answer (score 0):

client side. and it's very nice. It allows you to modify the DOM tree very efficiently and without hassle. Also, there are a lot of plugin libraries, allowing you to add new widgets and high-level functionality to the library in no time.

Answer (score 0):

It is a client-side library, in that all its code executes on the client.  But still, many of its functions require a server to be present to be meaningful.  I discovered this when trying to use the load() function from jquery. It's the server that provides the data;  the client will not look on the filesystem.